# Does lodash or underscore each method run in parallel in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I know that in node everything runs in parallel, except your code. Read [here](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb) and [here](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/).

I’m looking a possible scenario where I have a very large array in memory and I want to perform a small computation to each of its elements. The order in which this computation executes is not important.

In node all I/O is executed very efficiently because of the event loop but when you iterate through a collection there is no I/O involved and if this iteration takes too long you can block all incoming requests in that period of time.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/neilk/5380684#file-nonblockingforeach-js) contains a nonBlockingForEach that Neilk wrote in his article [Why you should use Node.js for CPU-bound tasks](http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/) which makes me wonder if I write something like this

```
var my_very_large_array = [...];
my_very_large_array.forEach(function() { ... })
//or
_.each(my_very_large_array, function() { ... })
```

I will hit a performance bottleneck on my server (this libraries fallback to the native forEach if present)

From what I learned you there are a lot of libraries like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to do that but I always use lodash or underscore for those tasks in the browser.

I also tried [bluebird.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) but promisifying those methods didn't work as expected.

So my question is this. Is lodash or underscore a performance killer in a node.js environment when you iterate through a large collection using a forEach method?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you not want your server to be blocked while processing? Your question, as asked, can be answered with a simple "no". Node is really fast. If you are only worried about looping over a large collection, skip lodash and underscore and just use a decrementing `while` loop.

Comment: Why a decrementing while loop will be better than a for loop or a forEach? Does this change in any way how your code is executed?

Comment: A decrementing while loop is faster than a regular for loop. It will be even faster on data sets as large as the question seems to indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new standard called "Web Workers" which do allow background work to happen in a separate thread in the same process. This requires later versions of node.js, and a separate package installed from here:

From the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker):

> The W3C and WHATWG envision web workers as long-running scripts that are not interrupted by user-interface scripts (scripts that respond to clicks or other user interactions). Keeping such workers from being interrupted by user activities should allow Web pages to remain responsive at the same time as they are running long tasks in the background.
>
> The simplest use of workers is for performing a computationally expensive task without interrupting the user interface.

You can enable Web workers in node.js by installing the [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) package

> So my question is this. Is lodash or underscore a performance killer in a node.js environment when you iterate through a large collection using a forEach method?

Yes, `lodash` and `underscore` will both kill performance in a typical node.js setup when working with a large amount of data, as they will block the only thread available, making other tasks queued up in the event-loop suffer. However if you were to run these in a web-worker thread, then your main thread would be free to continue processing work as normal.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. I just copy the phrase from the articles. I imagine that what the word means for node is that you distribute the job instead of block the whole proccess

Comment: What he is suggesting in that article at http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/ is that you can send your work to be done in another process.  You may want to look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads

Comment: Updated answer to mention "Web Workers".

Comment: Martin I see that you edited your answer and remove a part wich was the direct answer to my question and it was correct. Please modify your answer again to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I originally mentioned it was not possible - upon further research it appears that it is possible to run in a thread. Which part of the answer are you referring to?

Comment: Yes is possible to spawn more threads or proccess with the webworker-threads and the cluster modules but the forEach iterators will indeed block the main thread so your answer was correct. My question is about this methods.

Answer (score 1):

"Performance Killer" is a relative, and fairly loaded term.

To answer your direct question, does `forEach` in lodash or underscore run in parallel: no. It uses a standard, synchronous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is a single-thread single-process application. It does not matter if you process the entire array in a single forEach, or break it apart into multiple loops processed by the event queue. It's still going to take the same amount of work for that CPU core.

If you want to take advantage of multiple cores. You need to use the `cluster` module, and create multiple processes that work on different parts of the array.

There is no shared memory, or thread locking in NodeJS. So you will have to break apart the array into pieces for each process to work on.

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html